# Multiple paragraphSpacing in NSMutableParagraphStyle

Tags: ios, iphone, nsattributedstring, spacing, paragraph

In **NSMutableParagraphStyle** the **paragraphSpacing** Works perfectly fine.

but i am using **bullet points** also.

When user Press **Return(Enter)** then **new Paragraph** will come.

so when User type **bullet points** in ***Uitextview*** then in between two Points the **paragaph spacing** should be ***small*** and in rest of all the paragraph spacing is something high.

My code is...

```
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 0.f;
    paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 16.f;
    paragraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 16.0;
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 7.0;
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5.0;
    paragraphStyle.headIndent = 16.0;
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraphStyle.tailIndent=305.0;
    mutattstr1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:txtViewOfNotes.attributedText];
    [mutattstr1  addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, mutattstr1.length)];
    [txtViewOfNotes setAttributedText:mutattstr1];
```

Like in this text view i need to give small space in between two bullet points line.

[image]

So, how to get multiple line spacing or paragraph spacing or any other thing related to this in app.

Any kind of link, idea, code, dock is welcomed...

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple `NSMutableParagraphStyle` in the one `NSAttributedStrings` by using the range attributes - just like you've already done.

You'll just have to detect where you want each `NSMutableParagraphStyle` and apply with various `NSRange`. That's the "fun" part.

Comment: ya it is true but when user type the one paragraph and if the new paragraph will come with bullet point (means some more space from left side) then it will fluctuate and at the time of delete the text, also the text will fluctuate. if you solve this then the problem gone.